# Path based animation in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-animation

How to make a path-based animation with
 [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) E.G bezier curve.

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation? What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried http://www.eccesignum.org/blog/html5-canvas-drawing-library-exploration-paperjs but the paths which i have are random.

Comment: drake, edit your question and post **your** code. show us what you have tried and don't just link to articles.

Comment: For Bezier like paths read this http://html5tutorial.com/how-to-draw-n-grade-bezier-curve-with-canvas-api/ It was written in "basic" JavaScript so probably you can adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am creating a project that will allow you draw a canvas path and then animate anything else you draw along the path and then export the code for use in your own projects. Paths are built from joining cubic Bezier curves. A first version is available at http://canvimation.github.com/  with source code at https://github.com/canvimation/canvimation.github.com and help files at https://sites.google.com/site/canvimationhelp/.

I am currectly rewriting the code to make it more understandable and robust (stage 1 branch) but have not got to rewriting the animation sections yet. If any of the code is useful to you then you are welcome. Probable useful files are alongpath.js and buildmenu.js